# Why doesn't Microsoft provide support for older browsers and Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor-webassembly, backwards-compatibility

I've built my site using Blazor WASM. I need to provide guidance to our call center when a user calls and asks whether the site works in Chrome version xyz etc.

Microsoft supports the "Current" version.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-7.0

This isn't particularly helpful since we can only advise users - "make sure Chrome is up to date and try again".

Does "Current" mean "Stable Release"?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history

Is there a reason why Microsoft doesn't support N-1? I noticed Microsoft takes this approach to Azure Portal as well. I'm wondering if this is an industry trend.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-supported-browsers-devices

Comment: It's not about Microsoft support for browsers.  It's about browser support for WASM, html5, etc.  If you want a WASM framework website, you need a browser that can handle it, end of story.  Anyway-- anyone in 2023 who can't update their browser probably doesn't deservie to have an internet connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blazor wasm is supported by older versions of browsers that supports wasm (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera).

The initial version of wasm for each browser is listed here:
[image: Version]
source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly

**In theory** these versions should support blazor wasm.

That said... Microsoft putting **current+** is misleading.